# How to convert string to vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

If I have a string (from user) of "{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}", how would I convert that to a vector of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} in C++?

I tried to get a string from the user by

```
vector<int> input;
cin >> input;
```

but I got error:

```
./main.cpp:124:9: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'vector<int>')
    cin >> user_input;
```

Comment: You can't just wish and things happen. You need to read the documentation. You need to write code to make it happen. In particular: `int i; cin >> i; input.push_back(i)` is at least a place to start.

Comment: That string is also not trivially parsed with `>>` from `cin`. You may need to make your own class to represent it, and then implement `operator>>` to read it properly.

Comment: Check out [`std::basic_stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).  Convert your string into a `std::istringstream`, then use the `operator>>`.

Comment: You're not "converting a string to a vector", you're parsing the string into chunks, converting each chunk to an int, assuming it's formatted correctly, and then inserting the ints into a vector.

Comment: Get user input using `getline( std::cin, s )`, where `s` is a `std::string`.

Comment: you can try to read the characters one by one into the vector

Comment: or you can read the entire string then iterate through it by character and input it into the vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is where a library of useful functions comes in. I keep quite a few.

First, we’ll need something to range over a container (such as a string):

```
#include <utility>

template <typename Iterator>
struct ranger : public std::pair <Iterator, Iterator>
{
  ranger( Iterator begin, Iterator end = Iterator() ) : std::pair <Iterator, Iterator> { begin, end } { }
  Iterator begin() { return this->first;  }
  Iterator end  () { return this->second; }
};
```

Next we’ll want something to make iterating over a string with regular expressions easier:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

struct re_ranger : public std::regex, public ranger <std::sregex_iterator>
{
  template <typename RegEx>
  re_ranger( const RegEx& re, const std::string& s )
  : std::regex( re )
  , ranger( std::sregex_iterator( s.begin(), s.end(), *this ) )
  { }
};
```

And we will naturally want to have the ability to turn a string like `"7"` into an integer like `7`:

```
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
auto string_to( const std::string & s )
{
  T value;
  std::istringstream ss( s );
  return ((ss >> value) and (ss >> std::ws).eof())
    ? value
    : std::optional<T> { };
}
```

This makes selecting and converting the numbers in a string to a vector of integers stupidly simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::string input = "{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}";
  std::vector<int> xs;
  
  for (auto m : re_ranger( "[[:digit:]]+", input ))
    xs.emplace_back( *string_to<int>(m.str()) );
```

---

Since we are converting one way, we might as well be able to convert the other way. Here’s the freebie:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename Iterator>
std::string join( Iterator begin, Iterator end, const std::string & separator = " " )
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  if (begin != end)
  {
    ss << *begin++;
    while (begin != end)
      ss << separator << *begin++;
  }
  return ss.str();
}

template <typename Container>
std::string join( const Container & xs, const std::string & separator = " " )
{
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;
  return join( begin( xs ), end( xs ), separator );
}
```

Now we can finish off `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::string input = "{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}";
  std::vector<int> xs;
  
  for (auto s : re_ranger( "[[:digit:]]+", input ))
    xs.emplace_back( *string_to<int>( s.str() ) );
  
  std::cout << join( xs, "+" ) 
    << " = " << std::accumulate( xs.begin(), xs.end(), 0 ) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1+2+3+4+5 = 15
```

---

PS. You should get user input as a string:

```
int main()
{
  std::string input;
  std::cout << "input? ";
  getline( std::cin, input );
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:  convert your string into an input stream.
Try something like this:

```
const std::string   input_data="{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}";
std::istringstream  input_stream(input_data);
char                c; // Used for ignoring characters.  
std::vector<int>    database;
int                 number;

// Ignore the first brace
input_stream >> c;

// Read in the first number
input_stream >> number;
database.push_back(number);

// Read in the separator;
input_stream >> c;


// Read in the next number
input_stream >> number;
database.push_back(number);

// ...
```

The test for the ending brace or end of input are left as an exercise for the OP. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have this utility function I use to stream in specific characters like `{` and `}`

```
template<class e, class t>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e& cliteral) {
        e buffer;  //get buffer
        in >> buffer; //read data
        if (buffer != cliteral) //if it failed
                in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::failbit); //set the state
        return in;
}
```

And with that, you can use an `istream_iterator` to stream the `int`s that the user types directly into the vector:

```
std::cin >> '{';
std::vector<int> input(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {});
std::cin >> '}';
```

Comment: I have a similar function set, though I don’t think I’ll ever name a variable _cliteral_.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of parsing the input. It uses a helper type to **expect** a specific character in the input stream (and eat it).

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

struct expect
{
  char c;
  explicit expect( char c ) : c{c} { }
};

std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & ins, const expect & c )
{
  if (!std::isspace( (unsigned char)c.c )) ins >> std::ws;
  if (ins.peek() == c.c) ins.get();
  else ins.setstate( std::ios::failbit );
  return ins;
}
```

Now we can write our input function. I’ll overload `>>` for a vector of integers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & ins, std::vector<int> & xs )
{
  int x;
  xs.clear();
  if (!(ins >> expect( '{' ))) return ins;
  while (ins >> x)
  {
    xs.emplace_back( x );
    ins >> expect( ',' );
  }
  ins.clear();
  ins >> expect( '}' );
  return ins;
}
```

Notice how the function works: it *expects* specific input. If that input fails at any given time the stream will be set to a fail state and the function will return. Now we can use it much like I think you had planned in your question:

```
int main()
{
  std::string input = "{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}";
  
  std::vector<int> xs;
  std::istringstream ss( input );
  ss >> xs;
  
  for (int x : xs)
    std::cout << x << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Helper functions for the win!

---

PS. There is a companion function/class named `accept` which does nearly the same thing as `expect`. It just doesn’t set the fail state if the desired character is not next in the input stream.

```
struct accept
{
  char c;
  explicit accept( char c ) : c{c} { }
};

std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & ins, const accept & c )
{
  if (!std::isspace( (unsigned char)c.c )) ins >> std::ws;
  if (ins.peek() == c.c) ins.get();
  return ins;
}
```

These two functions are the basis for a lot of very useful parsing powers.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has since over 10 years a dedicated functionality for that. It is the

`std::sregex_token_iterator`

And since it is existing, and easy to handle, it should be used. The result is very often a one liner.

Please look at one potential solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

const std::regex re{ R"(\d+)" };

int main() {
    std::string s{ "{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}" };

    std::vector<int> result{};

    std::transform(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re), {}, std::back_inserter(result), [](const std::string& v) {return std::stoi(v); });

    for (const int i : result) std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

If you additionally want to validate the input, you can also use a `regex`.

Then the solution would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

const std::regex re{ R"(\d+)" };
const std::regex rv{ R"(\{(\d+\,)*\d+\})" };

int main() {
    // Read string and check input
    if (std::string s{}; std::getline(std::cin, s) and std::regex_match(s, std::regex{ R"(\{(\d+\,)*\d+\})" })) {

        std::vector<int> result{};

        // Extract intgers
        std::transform(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re), {}, std::back_inserter(result), [](const std::string& v) {return std::stoi(v); });

        // Show debug output
        for (const int i : result) std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n***Error: Invald input\n";
}
```

Input check can be relaxed with other `regex`es.